# Paypal Buy Now button - need add item id and name

Tags: paypal, payment

how i can add to my Paypal buy now button product id?
By default i can send only product name.

```
<input name = "item_name" value = "Product name" type = "hidden">
```

But i also need send and product id, then after payment i can get more information about all this process.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create PayPal - Buy Now button via PayPal Wizard - [here](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=fll8v4omBe3NMth_BMuiEkQZEdxM7dnaWOssrsT1vB30XvmOTgTUJiONjcW&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8d48a116ba977951b3435308b8c4dd4ef1). Here you can set `Item name` and `Item ID`. PayPal Button name is not a single button, its a form

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@email.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="TestItem">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123456789">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

Comment: "<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123456789">" - thanks!